# How to use regex to match file name and line number?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I need to parse all those lines using a single regex (preg_match_all) command:

```
at Object..test (resources/assets/js/tests/example.spec.js:423:23)
(/resources/assets/js/tests/example.spec.js:423)
/resources/assets/js/tests/example.spec.js:423
resources/assets/js/tests/example.spec.js:423
```

I should match (capturing groups) the file name and the line number

```
resources/assets/js/tests/example.spec.js
423
```

This is it (PHP) almost done: `(?:\()([\/]*.*\/[^:]*):([0-9]+)`, but it's not matching all of them, here's it on regex101:

https://regex101.com/r/hM2sK8/15

[image]

Comment: Why are you trying to match `(`? Wouldn't removing `(?:\())` work?

Comment: `(?:\()` works, but it does not match anything that doesn't starts with a `(`

Comment: Aren't you getting the filename and line number as you'd want, or do you want to match the last 2 lines as well? https://regex101.com/r/hM2sK8/16

Comment: But your demo is already working isn't it?

Comment: Yes it should match all lines.

Comment: I think https://regex101.com/r/hM2sK8/17 does it, are these all cases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you also want to catch nonparenthesized filenames, you'd be better served by capturing "something resembling a full path followed by colon and a number":

```
<?php
    $test = <<<TEST
at Object..test (resources/assets/js/tests/example.spec.js:423:23)
(/resources/assets/js/tests/example.spec.js:423)
/resources/assets/js/tests/example.spec.js:423
resources/assets/js/tests/example.spec.js:423
TEST;
    preg_match_all('#([A-Za-z0-9/\._-]+):([1-9][0-9]*)#', $test, $gregs, PREG_SET_ORDER);

   print implode(array_map(
       function ($set) {
            return "Found {$set[1]} at line {$set[2]}\n";
       },
       $gregs
    ));
```

returns:

```
Found resources/assets/js/tests/example.spec.js at line 423
Found /resources/assets/js/tests/example.spec.js at line 423
Found /resources/assets/js/tests/example.spec.js at line 423
Found resources/assets/js/tests/example.spec.js at line 423
```

## Getting unique file/line pairs

This might come in handy (`$gregs` is obtained as above):

```
    $pairs = array_map(
       function ($set) {
           if (0 !== strpos($set[1], '/')) {
               return [ "/{$set[1]}", $set[2] ];
           }
           return [ $set[1], $set[2] ];
       },
       $gregs
    );

    $pairs = array_map(
        'unserialize',
        array_unique(
            array_map(
                'serialize',
                $pairs
            )
        )
    );

    print_r($pairs);
```

Now `$pairs` only contains one pair.

Comment: You aren't using `.` or `^$` so the modifiers aren't needed. Also could shorten the regex a with metacharacters `([\w/.-]+):([1-9]\d*)`.

Comment: @chris85 , good catch on the modifiers. You're also right about metacharacters, but I usually prefer keeping them in plaintext. The parser will expand them anyway, and I feel that I'm more able to visualize the string this way. Of course those are just *my* tastes!

Comment: @AntonioCarlosRibeiro , one note - see that I used characters like - or _, and obviously . in file names. You might need to add other characters depending on your file naming scheme, for example "ClassOne,Debug.js" has a comma (I saw such a scheme once), and maybe spaces or @'s are possible.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this regex:

```
~(/?(?:[\w.-]+/)*[\w.-]+):(\d+)~
```

[Updated RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hM2sK8/19)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(/?(?:[\w.-]+/)*[\w.-]+)` matches and groups file resource path
- `:` match literal `:`
- `(\d+)` matches and groups number after `:`

Comment: It is not matching the first `/` on `(/resources/assets/js/tests/example.php:449)`

Comment: oh that is pretty easy to handle.. see updated regex.

Comment: btw accepted answer's regex will also match `////:35` as valid match.